# Send automated mails from excel with envelope

Tags: vba, excel, email, envelope

I have created this macro to send automatically mails via outlook! My macro runs but there is an issue. Instead of sending in the content of the mail only the value of the offset that I ask for, it sends the entire worksheet. I am providing the code below:

```
Dim ToArray As String
Dim CCArray As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim Content As String
Dim cell3 As Range

For Each cell3 In ws1.Range("D2:D" & lastrow1)
ToArray = cell3.Offset(0, 16).Value
CCArray = cell3.Offset(0, 17).Value
Subject = cell3.Offset(0, 18).Value
Content = cell3.Offset(0, 19).Value
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ws1.MailEnvelope
   .Introduction = Content
   .Item.To = ToArray
   .Item.CC = CCArray
   .Item.Subject = Subject
   .Item.Send
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Next cell3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use that:

```
Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

With Mail_Single
    .Subject = Subject
    .To = "email@address.com"
    .cc = "email@address.com"
    .BCC = "email@address.com"
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@address.com"
    .HTMLBody = Content
    .send
End With
```

Hope that helps...